# scrollToIndex out of range: request index1 but maximum is -1 .. React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, indexing

when I run my application it's okay and work If I create an array and put it in the data in FlatList like this array

```
const photos = [
  { id: 1, title: "Photo 1" },
  { id: 2, title: "Photo 2" },
  { id: 3, title: "Photo 3" },
  { id: 4, title: "Photo 4" },
  { id: 5, title: "Photo 5" },
  { id: 6, title: "Photo 6" },
];
```

But when I replace the photos array with an API, The app doesn't work. I tried more than API, I think the error is in my code not in the API,
This error appears to me " scrollToIndex out of range: request index1 but maximum is -1 "
What's wrong with my code?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import axios from "axios";


const phoneWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width;
const phoneHeight = Dimensions.get("screen").height;

function ScrollScreen() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [border, setBorder] = useState(0);
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const refBox = useRef();

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    photos();
  }, []);

  function photos() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
      .then(async function (response) {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    refContainer.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index }); 
  }, [index]);

  useEffect(() => {
    refBox.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index }); 
  }, [index]);

  const theNext = () => {
    if (index < photos.length - 1) {
      setIndex(index + 1);
      setBorder(index + 1);
    }
  };
  const thePrevious = () => {
    if (index > 0) {
      setIndex(index - 1);
      setBorder(index - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.con}>
      <AntDesign
        style={[styles.iconConPosition, { left: phoneWidth * 0.05 }]}
        onPress={thePrevious}
        size={55}
        color="#0dddcb"
        name="caretleft"
      />

      <AntDesign
        style={[styles.iconConPosition, { right: phoneWidth * 0.05 }]}
        onPress={theNext}
        size={55}
        color="#0dddcb"
        name="caretright"
      />

      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={false}
        ref={refContainer}
        data={data}
        // data={photos}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
        style={styles.flatList}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <View
            style={{
              height: 150,
              width: phoneWidth * 0.7,
              margin: 50,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              alignSelf: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled //تفعيل خاصية التمرير
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
      />

      <FlatList
        ref={refBox}
        data={data}
        // data={photos}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
        style={styles.flatList}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setIndex(index);
              setBorder(index);
            }}
            style={
              border === index
                ? {
                    height: 100,
                    width: phoneWidth * 0.4,
                    margin: 7,
                    backgroundColor: "gray",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: "blue",
                  }
                : {
                    height: 100,
                    width: phoneWidth * 0.4,
                    margin: 7,
                    backgroundColor: "gray",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                  }
            }
          >
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        horizontal
      />
      <Text>{index}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
export default ScrollScreen;
```

Comment: It's saying that 'index' is 1 inside the scrollToIndex method, but it can't be higher than -1. This error doesn't seem related to the array you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `data` is an empty array, but `index` is set to `0`. On the first invocation of the `useEffect` that tries to scroll, there is an error because `scrollToIndex(0)` is an error when `data` is empty, since there is no item for index `0`.

Try initializing the `border` and `index` state to `-1` instead of `0` like:

```
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(-1);
  const [border, setBorder] = useState(-1);
```

On a separate but related note the `theNext` function has an error, it should be checking `data.length` instead of `photos.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue just now. Using ScrollToOffSet({offset: number, animated: boolean}) instead of scrollToIndex solved the issue for me